# Error in Azure DevOps SQL Server database deploy task not failing pipeline

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using Azure DevOps [`SQL Server database deploy`](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroupV0/README.md) task to run a SQL Server Agent Job using its inline SQL feature which works.

However if the job fails I have some logic that generates an error from the SQL script as per below. When the script errors, that error correctly gets displayed in the task logs, however it **doesn't** fail the whole task but rather returns a `succeeded` status. This confuses the developer as they think their changes are not breaking the job when in fact they are.

Is there anyway to bubble up the error generated form the SQL script so that the `SQL Server database deploy` task returns a `failed` status instead of a `succeeded` status.

Please see screen shots and YAML of the release issue below:

[image]

[image]

```yaml
steps:
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'Run SQL Agent Job'
  inputs:
    TaskType: sqlInline
    InlineSql: |
     /* SQL Agent Job Logic Here... */
     
     /* Raise error if job fails */
     
     RAISERROR('##vso[task.logissue type=error]]%s job has either failed or is not in a good state!', 16, 1, 'JobName') WITH LOG
    DatabaseName: master
    AdditionalArgumentsSql: '-QueryTimeout 1800 -IncludeSqlUserErrors -OutputSqlErrors 1 -Verbose'
```

Comment: According to Azure DevOps, this step is deprecated. Maybe it's just not functioning correctly because of changes in how the DevOps pipeline works? Guessing a bit here. Based on overall function, you should see an error.

Comment: Do you have a link saying it has been deprecated? Its not obvious looking at the documentation or when I search for SQL Deploy in the Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Task GUI. Do you know if there is a replacement release task I should be using instead?

Comment: When I looked it up in order to try to help, it was only available on the deprecation list.

Comment: As to what to use instead, I'd probably just go for a powershell command myself.

Answer (score 1):

> Error in Azure DevOps SQL Server database deploy task not failing pipeline

You could try to use the [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to fail build from your Inline Sql scripts:

```
##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]DONE
```

> `##vso[task.complete]current operation`
>
> `result=Succeeded|SucceededWithIssues|Failed`
>
> **Finish timeline record for current task, set task result and current
> operation**. When result not provided, set result to succeeded. Example:
> `##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]DONE`

Comment: I tried this using RAISERROR('##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]DONE', 1, 1) and PRINT('##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]DONE') at the end of the inline sql script but get the error below. This happens with both a Failed and Succeeded result.

2020-07-24T10:47:51.1356154Z ##[error]The pipeline has been stopped.
2020-07-24T10:47:51.1368181Z ##[error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object.